# Where are these tailing digits in Python value from?

Tags: python, floating-point, limit, numeric, significant-digits

In mathematics, the value 1/3 is 0.333(3 to infinity).

However, Python prints out wrong digits at the tail.

```
print(f"{1/3:.100f}".rstrip("0"));
print(f"{1/3:.100f}");
```

Result:

0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125

Result (no rstrip):

0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Where are those tailing digits (which are not 3) from?

Comment: Could this be an error this `rstrip` function you are using? If not, it could be something similar to what BigDecimal fixes in Java.

Comment: without rstrip, the digits at tail are still random

Comment: no, im asking about the value in python

Comment: Floating point inaccuracies exist no matter what language it is. I think the marked duplicate goes into more depth about why these inaccuracies exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

> Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions

For decimal fractions which cannot be represented as binary fractions (e.g. repeating decimals) they are approximated by a binary fraction up to the precision limit:

> Stop at any finite number of bits, and you get an approximation. On most machines today, floats are approximated using a binary fraction with the numerator using the first 53 bits [...]

Hence, `1/3.` is not stored as `0.333....` (repeating) but as an approximation (ostensibly a 53-bit binary fraction).

Answer (score 1):

As you add more precise values, python calculates a number closer to the actual value. Think about it this way, using 1/3:

`0.3`

or

`0.33`

or

`0.333`

"No matter how many digits you’re willing to write down, the result will never be exactly 1/3, but will be an increasingly better approximation of 1/3."

Comment: oh ok, so it's approximated digits, not random digits, tks